# Convert the first column data type from float to int, and write back to the original csv file

Tags: python, csv, type-conversion

I want to change the data type of the first column from float to integer, and store integers in the original file. Here's some of my code.

```
import csv 

with open("data.csv", r) as f: 
  csvreader = csv.reader(f) 
  for row in csvreader: 
    i = int(row[0]) # first column of the row
```

Then I don't know how to modify the original csv file after this step. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do so very easily by using pandas:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv("data.csv")

df["col"] = df["col"].astype(int)

df.to_csv("data.csv", index=False)
```

if you don't know the name of the first column and want to using integer based indexing, then do this:

`df.iloc[:, 0] = df.iloc[:, 0].astype(int)`